# Border hover effect with CSS

Tags: css, hover, border-layout

I tried to replicate a border hover effect but I didn't understand why I need to use ::before and ::after to do this Css effect.

This is the page example with the content that I want to replicate with css (I want to replicate the border effect):

http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/pagina-di-test/

This is the homepage where I tried to replicate the css:

http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/

In the first row there is the "example" and in the row below there is my attempt

This is the code that I made:

```css
round {
  background-image: url('http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/a.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
.layer {
  background-color: rgba(18, 29, 47, 0.96);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 20px 200px 20px;
}
.div-diviso {
  width: 17%;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.div-diviso img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.div-diviso .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -o-transform: scale(0.1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.div-diviso:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  visibility: visible;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  transform: border scale3d(0, 1, 1);
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  .layer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .div-diviso {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .layer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .div-diviso {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="layer">
    <div class="div-diviso">
      <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SILVIA-FAIT-2017_980.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-diviso">
      <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CLAUDIO-ZAMPARELLI-2017_980.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-diviso">
      <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ROBERTA-MAGNANI-2017_980.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-diviso">
      <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/BARBARA-VANNI-2017_980.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-diviso">
      <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SANDRO-CAMPANI-2017_980.jpg">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
    </div>
    </dvi>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot animate borders from the middle natively in css. They will auto transition from the starting point of the `div` (or from the opposite end if you want to use a `transform: rotate(180deg)`). Hence, the usage of the `::before` & `::after` elements.

Also, `transform: border scale3d(0, 1, 1);` is invalid as `border` is not a CSS3 property applicable to `transform`.

If you do not want to use the pseudo elements, then you can use a late appearance of the border on the overlay. However it won't animate from the middle.

Modify your css as:

```
.div-diviso:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    visibility: visible;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    transition: border 0.75s;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you do want to use the pseudo selectors, apply the following css:

```
.div-diviso:hover .overlay:before, .div-diviso:hover .overlay:after {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.div-diviso .overlay:before, .div-diviso .overlay:after {
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 9;
}

.div-diviso .overlay:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-top: 3px solid #20bed0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #20bed0;
}

.div-diviso .overlay:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 3px solid #20bed0;
    border-right: 3px solid #20bed0;
}
```

Comment: I would like to use pseudo elements but I did a lot of attempts without reach the goal. "transition: border 0.75s;" is only a substitution. Can you explain me how I could do this with pseudo elements?

Comment: @Matteo Check the Edited version of the answer.